# Maximal ideals of the ring $R=C(\mathbb R)$ of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R=C(\mathbb R)$ be the ring of continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ where the addition and the product is pointwise defined.  Let $$\mathbb m_a=\{f\in R\ |\ f(a)=0\}$$ 
>   be a maximal ideal. Show
>   when $\mathbb m_a=\mathbb m_b$ it implies that $a=b$.

Why is that true?

Comment: @Serge: Use a bump function around $ a $ whose support excludes $ b $.

Comment: $x-a \in \Bbb{m}_a \setminus \Bbb{m}_b$ if and only if $a \neq b$.

Comment: @EricTowers Would you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on a comment ...

Let $a \in \Bbb{C}$ be given and define $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{C}: x \mapsto x-a$.  We see $f \in R$, because $f$ is a polynomial, and further that $f \in \Bbb{m}_a$, because $f(a) = a-a = 0$.  Now $f(b) = b-a$ is zero if and only if $a = b$.  That is, $f \in \Bbb{m}_b$ if and only if $a = b$.   But $\Bbb{m}_a = \Bbb{m}_b$ implies $f \in \Bbb{m}_b$.  Therefore, $\Bbb{m}_a = \Bbb{m}_b$ implies $a=b$.